# Why does this line of code doing stuff to a string[] return as bool?

Tags: c#, string

```
tableLR = txt
    .Split("Sat.")[i + 1]
    .Split("  ")
    .ToList()
    .Remove(txt
        .Split("Sat.")[i + 1]
        .Split("  ")
        .ToList()[txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList().Count() - 1]);
```

The variable being set is `List<string> tableLR`

the variable being processed is `string txt`

okay, `List<T>.Remove()`returns bool. But then how am I supposed to set `tableLR` to that 'txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList()' with the last item in the 'txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList()' removed?

Comment: Because `List<T>.Remove()` returns a bool. This expression is hard to read due to its length. It evaluates the subexpression `txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList()` three times. Should probably factor out the common subexpression.

Comment: Which is the outermost final function that will be called in that line? And what it returns?

Comment: *"how am I supposed to set tableLR to that [list]"* Break the line into two parts - capture the list first, then remove an item.

Comment: Unfortunately LINQ `Except()` may not be usable here because it returns only unique items from the first collection which aren't present in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's reformat:

```
int num = txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList().Count() - 1; // n is list length - 1
string s = txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList()[num]; // return item in list
bool result = txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList().Remove(s); // remove item from list
```

Remove returns bool (docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netcore-3.1)

and as you can see from code above, it always be true.

To anser your follow-up question:

```
tableLR = txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList();
tableLR.RemoveAt(tableLR.Count - 1);
```

Comment: This is the only correct answer that removes the last entry and only the last entry.  Other methods are likely to remove all entries equal to the last one, no matter where in the list they appear.

Comment: @RufusL: "set tableLR to that (expression) with the last item in the (same expression) removed" is explicitly stated as a goal in the question, it's just easy to overlook because it's buried in mis-formatted code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah, I did miss that

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to see why if you format it like this:

```cs
tableLR = txt
    .Split("Sat.")[i + 1]
    .Split("  ")
    .ToList()
    .Remove(
        txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1]
        .Split("  ")
        .ToList()[
            txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1]
            .Split("  ")
            .ToList()
            .Count() - 1
        ]
    );
```

The last thing really being called there is `.Remove` which returns true or false based on whether the object was removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableLR = txt.Split("Sat.")[i + 1].Split("  ").ToList();
tableLR.Remove(tableLR[tableLR.Count() - 1]);
```